# In Wordpress, my Javascript is sensitive to line breaks?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax-error

Is Javascript under any circumstances meant to be sensitive to line breaks? I'm under the impression that it is not, as for example I know that js code is often "[minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))".

I'm developing on WordPress, if that may make any difference, but I've boiled it down to the following minimal example. I have one html element: `<p id="my-test"></p>` and one script. The following script works just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){doSomething();}
function doSomething() { 
    document.getElementById("my-test").innerHTML = "Hello world.";
    var meaningOfLife = 42;
}
</script>
```

But if I add one line break as follows it stops working altogether:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){doSomething();}
function doSomething() { 
    document.getElementById("my-test").innerHTML = "Hello world.";

    var meaningOfLife = 42;
}
</script>
```

Please illuminate me before I go insane. I've tried to keep it minimal, but if you need any more details, just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, line breaks matter when you forget or omit semicolons. Google "automatic semicolon insertion".

Comment: As a good practice, you should always insert semicolons.

Comment: Protip: `window.onload = doSomething;`

Comment: Sorry both, I had only forgotten to include the semicolon in the SO question, I have confired that it is there in my code. Phenomenon remains. :/

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @canon I know: in fact I first wrote my code in jsFiddle and then pasted it into my WordPress editor once it was working fine. It stopped working, and after stripping it down I realized the problem was the line breaks.

Comment: @canon Not being able to reproduce is not a reason for a downvote. Technically, this shouldn't happen, but it is happening. mga, what's the actual error that you're getting, if any? When you look at the JS in the developer console, do you see your script at all?

Comment: @canon Sorry, but a -1 just because you cannot reproduce it on jsFiddle is ridiculous. The question still remains: why does it behave like that on WordPress.

Comment: @mga do you get any error on console? Did you check the view source to see if this code is changed in any way?

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". Here's the page: http://www.melvingauci.com/?page_id=65

Comment: I've added the `Wordpress` tag to this question, as I think that your issue is likely related to Wordpress in some way. Line breaks should have no effect aside from automatic semicolon insertion in Javascript.

Comment: @mga the output source code is `document.getElementsByClassName("my-test")[0].innerHTML = "Hello world.";</p>
<p>` inside the script tag, no wonder there is an issue

Comment: Ah ... on view source, I can see that Wordpress is adding tags to my code for some reason: document.getElementsByClassName("my-test")[0].innerHTML = "Hello world.";</p>
<p>    var meaningOfLife = 42;

Comment: Your error points to this `window.onload = function(){setLayout();};
function setLayout() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("my-test")[0].innerHTML = "Hello world.";</p>
<p>    var meaningOfLife = 42;
}`. You have HTML in with your JS.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem is indeed that WordPress is adding tags to my code. Sorry for being naive and not checking the output source first - I'm only a beginner in web development. But wouldn't this question be a useful reference for anyone who tries to insert a script in WP and gets the same problem?

Comment: @Kevin B Said person may be an idiot like me, but will hopefully find this question and then follow your excellent advice on seeing the comment. :)

Comment: Ultimately it's one of those problems that you'll only run into if you're doing something you shouldn't be doing anyway, such as writing inline javascript.

Comment: @Kevin B This will be my last reply to you, but just to give you some context, I'm simply writing a small personal homepage and decided learning some javascript along the way wouldn't harm. A beginner may or may not know that inlining js is not good practice. It may also not be as obvious to them to check the output source as you may think, because it comes naturally to you after years of experience. I came across something weird, and instead of just doing whatever worked and be done with it, I took some time to say "wtf" and learn something. I'm genuinely sorry if I inconvenienced you.

Comment: You didn't, i'm just pointing out the obvious (to me) so that someone who doesn't know those things may get the hint. No harm intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

WordPress is apparently parsing consecutive newlines and adding `<p>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){setLayout();};
function setLayout() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("my-test")[0].innerHTML = "Hello world.";</p>
<p>    var meaningOfLife = 42;
}
</script>
```

That's not allowed in `<script>`.